# How to rotate the exported svg in Inkscape?

Tags: svg, inkscape

Short question:
I'm using Inkscape v0.92 on macOS 10.13 to draw a SVG-image. Everytime i try to export the image to a 'raw' SVG file via the "print"-dialog it rotates the original image 90 degrees, so it's vertical at the end.

The print dialog doesn't show me any option to rotate the image or do something similar.

Is there any solution for that?

Maybe this could be fixed by using command line instead of the GUI?!

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you want to end up with a SVG file, why do you use the Print function?

Comment: @ccprog Thanks for your response. As far as i know the print job reduces the filesize by removing Inkscape specific metadata. Correct me if i'm wrong :)

Comment: No, it converts the file to a printer language like Postscript. Open "Save as..." and choose the "Plain SVG" format to remove the Inkscape-specific elements and attributes. (Metadata in the rdf namespace, btw, are not among them.)

Comment: Optimized SVG will make it even smaller. Make sure to save it as a copy, because it will lose some of the editor data that will come in handy if you ever want to edit the file again.